# Trouble solving exercise

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, curves, residue-calculus

**Exercise.** Evaluate
\begin{equation*}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{2k}}{1+x^{2n}}dx
\end{equation*}
, where $0\leq k < n$ and $n,k \in \mathbb{N_0}$

**My attempt.** I have tried to solve the integral through the residues method,i.e., completing the segment $[-R,R]$ with a curve $C_R$ such that $|z| = R, Im(z)\geq 0$ and then declaring that
\begin{equation*}
\int_D \dots = \int_{-R}^{R}\dots + \int_{C_R} \dots
\end{equation*}
, where
\begin{equation*}
\int_D f(x)dx= 2\pi i \sum_{a_j \in int(D)}Res(f,a_j)
\end{equation*}
By calculating $f$ singularities I've that $x=\sqrt[n]{i}$ is a pole of order $n$.

But how I am stuck calculating the associated residues. Is there some alternative method to solve this? Thanks for ali the helpin advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got [nerdsniped](https://xkcd.com/356/) and ended up solving the problem.  Hope it helps you.

Let $f(z) = \dfrac{z^{2k}}{z^{2n}+1}$.  If $\omega$ is any $2n$th root of $-1$, then $f$ has simple pole at $\omega$ and
\begin{align*}
    \operatorname{Res}(f,\omega)
    &= \lim_{z\to\omega} \frac{z^{2k}(z-\omega)}{z^{2n} - \omega^{2n}}
    \\&= \frac{\omega^{2k}}{2n\omega^{2n-1}} = - \frac{\omega^{2k+1}}{2n}
\end{align*}
Set $\omega = \exp\left(\frac{\pi i}{2n}\right)$.  The $2n$th roots of $-1$ that are in the upper half-plane are $\omega, \omega^3, \omega^5, \dots, \omega^{2n-1}$.  Using your contour notation and assuming $R > 1$,
\begin{align*}
    \int_D f(z)\,dz 
    &= 2\pi i \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \operatorname{Res}(f,\omega^{2j+1})
    \\&= -\frac{\pi i}{n} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (\omega^{2j+1})^{2k+1}
    \\&= -\frac{\pi i}{n} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (\omega^{2k+1})^{2j+1}
\end{align*}
Let $\zeta = \omega^{2k+1}$.  Then
\begin{align*}
    \int_D f(z)\,dz 
    &= -\frac{\pi i}{n} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \zeta^{2j+1}
    = -\frac{\pi i \zeta}{n} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (\zeta^2)^j
    \\&= - \frac{\pi i\zeta}{n} \left(\frac{1 - \zeta^{2n}}{1-\zeta^2}\right)
    = -\frac{2\pi i}{n} \cdot \frac{\zeta}{1-\zeta^2}
\end{align*}
(since $\zeta^{2n} = (\omega^{2k+1})^{2n} = (\omega^{2n})^{2k+1} = 1$).

Since $|\zeta| = 1$, $\zeta^{-1} = \bar\zeta$.  So
\begin{align*}
    \frac{\zeta}{1-\zeta^2}
    &= \frac{\zeta}{1-\zeta^2} \cdot \frac{\bar\zeta}{\bar\zeta}
    \\&= \frac{1}{\bar\zeta - \zeta} = \frac{i}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{\Im(\zeta)}
\end{align*}
Therefore,
$$
    \int_D f(z)\,dz  = \frac{\pi}{n \Im(\zeta)}
$$
The integral over $C_R$ is bounded by $\pi R^{2(k-n)+1}$, which (since $0 \leq k < n$) tends to zero as $R\to\infty$.  Also, by Euler's formula,
$$
    \zeta = \exp\left(\frac{(2k+1)\pi i}{2n}\right)
    = \cos \left(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2n}\right) 
      + i \sin \left(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2n}\right)
$$
Therefore,
$$
    \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^{2k}\,dx}{1+x^{2n}} = \frac{\pi}{n} \csc \left(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2n}\right)
$$

Comment: Obviously it does! Really Thankfull

Answer (score 1):

The function $$f(z)= \frac{z^{2k}}{1+z^{2n}} = \frac{z^{2k}}{(1+iz^{n})(1-iz^n)} $$

has poles where $$z^n = e^{\pi i/2} \text{ and } z^n = e^{-\pi i/2} $$

That is at $$z \in \{e^{\pi i (2k+1/2)/n},e^{\pi i (2k-1/2)/n} \}, \quad k=0,1,\cdots,n-1$$

Comment: Sounds right... How would I calculate its order and its residues thought? Thanks!

Comment: First, you need to determine which of these are in the upper-half plane.  Each pole is of order $1.$

Comment: Thanks! I Guess I can do it now! Really apreciatted

Comment: You are welcome!